# libcurl: Is there any way to get certificates of FTPS without logging in?

Tags: c, ftp, openssl, certificate, libcurl

libcurl can get certificate info by using [`CURLINFO_CERTINFO`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html#CURLINFOCERTINFO), but that info must come after `curl_easy_perform`, which means you need to log in to the FTP server first without verifying the certificates.

FTP software like FileZilla get the certificates and then ask the user to trust them or not, just before sending username and password.

The following OpenSSL command can also get the certificates with no username or password:

`$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ftp.godaddy.com:21 -starttls ftp`

I also tried using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to monitor the FTP commands.  After `AUTH TLS` command is OK, it'll stop immediately and try to get the cert info.  But that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using the `CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION` to install a callback function when the `SSL_CTX` gets created. From that CURL callback, you can install your own verify function callback using the regular OpenSSL API `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback()`.

The [CURL web site](http://curl.haxx.se/) provides [an example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curlx.html).